# @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) in hyperjaxb?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, hyperjaxb

How do I set a collection to be `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` in hyperjaxb?

**Here is the example:**  I have an xml node `ab` which can contain either a list of subnodes of type `cd` or a list of subnodes of type `ef`.  Both `cd` and `ef` only contain textual/string content.  I have an xsd definition of this which I run through JAXB and hyperjaxb to create java classes with hibernate annotations complete with database tables.  Instead of setting fetchtype, how do I get hyperjaxb to set `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` for each collection?

The xml looks like:

```
<ab>
    <cd>Some thing</cd>
    <cd>Another thing</cd>
</ab>
```

or:

```
<ab>
    <ef>Some thing</ef>
    <ef>Another thing</ef>
</ab>
```

The xsd looks like:

```
<xs:complexType name="Ab">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="cd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="ef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The resulting entity should look like:

```
@Entity(name = "Ab")
@Table(name = "AB")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Ab implements Equals, HashCode {

    protected List<String> cd;
    protected List<String> ef;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Hjid")
    protected Long hjid;
    protected transient List<Ab.AbCdItem> cdItems;
    protected transient List<Ab.AbEfItem> efItems;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Ab.AbCdItem.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_ITEMS_AB_HJID")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public List<Ab.AbCdItem> getCdItems() {
        if (this.cdItems == null) {
            this.cdItems = new ArrayList<Ab.AbCdItem>();
        }
        if (ItemUtils.shouldBeWrapped(this.cd)) {
            this.cd = ItemUtils.wrap(this.cd, this.cdItems, Ab.AbCdItem.class);
        }
        return this.cdItems;
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Ab.AbEfItem.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "EF_ITEMS_AB_HJID")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public List<Ab.AbEfItem> getEfItems() {
        if (this.efItems == null) {
            this.efItems = new ArrayList<Ab.AbEfItem>();
        }
        if (ItemUtils.shouldBeWrapped(this.ef)) {
            this.ef = ItemUtils.wrap(this.ef, this.efItems, Ab.AbEfItem.class);
        }
        return this.efItems;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@LazyCollection`, or [`@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/LazyCollection.html) (in fully qualified form) is a proprietary Hibernate annotation, not JPA standard.

Hyperjaxb only supports standard JPA 1.0 and 2.0 annotations, so `@LazyCollection` is not supported.

Optons:

- You can use [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](/questions/tagged/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) to add arbitrary annotations to schema-derived classes. So [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](/questions/tagged/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) will allow you to add `@LazyCollection` to the target properties. However, you will need to customize each and every property you want `@LazyCollection` to appear on.
- Hyperjaxb supports so-called *variants* (different generation modes). For instance this is the configuration of the [JPA 1.0 variant](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/plugin/src/main/resources/org/jvnet/hyperjaxb3/ejb/jpa1/plugin/applicationContext.xml) and this is the [JPA 2.0 variant](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/plugin/src/main/resources/org/jvnet/hyperjaxb3/ejb/jpa2/plugin/applicationContext.xml). You can extend Hyperjaxb by writing and configuring a new *variant* for Hibernate which would support Hibernate-specific annotations and customizations. However, this is rather advanced. Would take me personaly a few days to implement.